# Can 'that' in appositive clauses be omitted:The fact they do not is interesting?

Tags: grammar

From Rodney Huddleston Geoffrey K Pullum. (2017). The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. p.6.

> Although descriptive grammars and prescriptive usage manuals differ in
> the range of topics they treat, there is no reason in principle why
> they should not agree on what they say about the topics they both
> treat. **The fact they do not is interesting.**

Should it be 'The fact [that] *they do not agree on what they say about the topics they both treat* is interesting'?

Comment: "That" is entirely optional.  Can you explain (perhaps with reference to the text book) why you think it is required.  Please give a reference to the page that says you need "that".

Comment: @Mr Wang Are you seriously doubting the correctness of the authors' grammar in CGEL?  What research have you done on the conditions under which "that" must or may not appear? Incidentally, the clause is not an appositive one.

Comment: @BillJ If not, what kind of clause is it?

Comment: "They do not" is a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "fact".  See CGEL p448 (top) for more information.

Comment: @BillJ His analysis is a bit far-fetched. No reason is given for why it is not an appositive.

Comment: For those of us who don't have access to CGEL, what disqualifies the content-clause for appositive role? "The fact ... is interesting."  "that they do not agree is interesting".  The NP and the content-clause have the same syntactic role relative to the verb-phrase. I'm thinking it must be that a content clause by definition is non-referential. Declarations are not references.

Comment: How about "That fact, namely, that they do not agree, is interesting"?

Comment: @Mr.Wang That''s not true. It most certainly does give a reason, and it explains it very clearly. And on what grounds do you, as a non-native speaker, think it to be "a bit far fetched"?